# Unable to install fasttext through terminal using make

Tags: makefile, fasttext

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 and am trying to install fasttext through terminal using the following commands (from their website):

```
$ wget https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/archive/v0.2.0.zip
$ unzip v0.2.0.zip
$ cd fastText-0.2.0
$ make
```

But I am getting the following error when I try to make it:

```
c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -c src/args.cc
c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -c src/dictionary.cc
c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -c src/productquantizer.cc
c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -c src/matrix.cc
c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -c src/qmatrix.cc
c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -c src/vector.cc
c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -c src/model.cc
c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -c src/utils.cc
c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -c src/meter.cc
c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops -c src/fasttext.cc
src/fasttext.cc: In member function ‘void fasttext::FastText::quantize(const fasttext::Args&)’:
src/fasttext.cc:302:16: warning: ‘std::vector<int> fasttext::FastText::selectEmbeddings(int32_t) const’ is deprecated: selectEmbeddings is being deprecated. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     auto idx = selectEmbeddings(qargs.cutoff);
                ^
src/fasttext.cc:279:22: note: declared here
 std::vector<int32_t> FastText::selectEmbeddings(int32_t cutoff) const {
                      ^
src/fasttext.cc:302:45: warning: ‘std::vector<int> fasttext::FastText::selectEmbeddings(int32_t) const’ is deprecated: selectEmbeddings is being deprecated. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     auto idx = selectEmbeddings(qargs.cutoff);
                                             ^
src/fasttext.cc:279:22: note: declared here
 std::vector<int32_t> FastText::selectEmbeddings(int32_t cutoff) const {
                      ^
src/fasttext.cc: In member function ‘void fasttext::FastText::lazyComputeWordVectors()’:
src/fasttext.cc:531:5: warning: ‘void fasttext::FastText::precomputeWordVectors(fasttext::Matrix&)’ is deprecated: precomputeWordVectors is being deprecated. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     precomputeWordVectors(*wordVectors_);
     ^
src/fasttext.cc:514:6: note: declared here
 void FastText::precomputeWordVectors(Matrix& wordVectors) {
      ^
src/fasttext.cc:531:40: warning: ‘void fasttext::FastText::precomputeWordVectors(fasttext::Matrix&)’ is deprecated: precomputeWordVectors is being deprecated. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     precomputeWordVectors(*wordVectors_);
                                        ^
src/fasttext.cc:514:6: note: declared here
 void FastText::precomputeWordVectors(Matrix& wordVectors) {
      ^
src/fasttext.cc: In member function ‘void fasttext::FastText::trainThread(int32_t)’:
src/fasttext.cc:650:7: warning: ‘void fasttext::FastText::supervised(fasttext::Model&, fasttext::real, const std::vector<int>&, const std::vector<int>&)’ is deprecated: supervised is being deprecated. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       supervised(model, lr, line, labels);
       ^
src/fasttext.cc:338:6: note: declared here
 void FastText::supervised(
      ^
src/fasttext.cc:650:41: warning: ‘void fasttext::FastText::supervised(fasttext::Model&, fasttext::real, const std::vector<int>&, const std::vector<int>&)’ is deprecated: supervised is being deprecated. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       supervised(model, lr, line, labels);
                                         ^
src/fasttext.cc:338:6: note: declared here
 void FastText::supervised(
      ^
src/fasttext.cc:653:7: warning: ‘void fasttext::FastText::cbow(fasttext::Model&, fasttext::real, const std::vector<int>&)’ is deprecated: cbow is being deprecated. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       cbow(model, lr, line);
       ^
src/fasttext.cc:355:6: note: declared here
 void FastText::cbow(Model& model, real lr, const std::vector<int32_t>& line) {
      ^
src/fasttext.cc:653:27: warning: ‘void fasttext::FastText::cbow(fasttext::Model&, fasttext::real, const std::vector<int>&)’ is deprecated: cbow is being deprecated. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       cbow(model, lr, line);
                           ^
src/fasttext.cc:355:6: note: declared here
 void FastText::cbow(Model& model, real lr, const std::vector<int32_t>& line) {
      ^
src/fasttext.cc:656:7: warning: ‘void fasttext::FastText::skipgram(fasttext::Model&, fasttext::real, const std::vector<int>&)’ is deprecated: skipgram is being deprecated. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       skipgram(model, lr, line);
       ^
src/fasttext.cc:371:6: note: declared here
 void FastText::skipgram(
      ^
src/fasttext.cc:656:31: warning: ‘void fasttext::FastText::skipgram(fasttext::Model&, fasttext::real, const std::vector<int>&)’ is deprecated: skipgram is being deprecated. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       skipgram(model, lr, line);
                               ^
src/fasttext.cc:371:6: note: declared here
 void FastText::skipgram(
      ^
c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -march=native -O3 -funroll-loops args.o dictionary.o productquantizer.o matrix.o qmatrix.o vector.o model.o utils.o meter.o fasttext.o src/main.cc -o fasttext
```

I don't know what is causing the error. As far as I have figure, these are depreciation warnings and make is treating them errors. Is there anyway to suppress this behaviour of make?
Or is there any other way to install fasttext?

I read from somewhere and tried `make -i` but it is also giving the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in version v0.9.1. They are just warnings. My binary still compiled with just the warnings.

```
./fasttext
```